# How can I delete a document's headers with AppleScript

Tags: ms-word, applescript

When I tried to delete Document 1's headers.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set headers to get story range document 1 story type primary header story
    delete headers
end tell
```

I got a problem **"Microsoft Word got an error: Can’t get document "Document1"." number -1728 from document "Document1"**

Why?

I open a document, and set a header.So the document 1 exist.When I tried this code.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set headers to get story range document 1 story type primary header story
    get content of headers
end tell
```

It's all right.And get the header's text content.

Comment: Error 1728 means that something you're trying to work with doesn't exist (e.g. document 2 when there is only a document 1). If I open a blank document (in Word 2011), the script above runs fine (but doesn't actually do anything since the document has no header). Is there more to the script that isn't above? Or do you have zero documents open?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should avoid creating variable **headers**, which is reserved word (property). Test following snippet yourself, because I don't use Microsoft Word at all.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    tell (story range document 1 story type primary header story)
      delete its headers
   end tell
end tell
```